# Select Common Column Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, relational-division, having-clause

I have a SQL table like

```
 docid            State
12                  MP
13                  MP
14                  MP
13                  CG
14                  CG
12                  MH
13                  MH
16                  DL
```

I want a SQL query where I can get a result with only common "docid" for all the three states "MP","CG","MH"

Like

```
Docid   
13
```

Note: States are entered from user id in Where states = ""

Comment: Search for *Relational Division*

Comment: Also, have you researched this question on the site?  It gets asked a lot here.

Comment: I have done attempts but cannot find correct Answer as i am using where state in ('MP','CG','MH') so it will show result for any of the states.

Comment: Show your attempts and the current output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used sqlite3 to reproduce your scenario using the following SQL commands:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    docid INT,
    State VARCHAR(2)
);
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (12,'MP');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (13,'MP');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (14,'MP');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (13,'CG');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (14,'CG');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (12,'MH');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (13,'MH');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (16,'DL');
```

Then I was able to query what you are looking for using:

```
SELECT mp.docid AS Docid
FROM tablename AS mp
JOIN tablename AS cg ON mp.docid = cg.docid
JOIN tablename AS mh ON cg.docid = mh.docid
WHERE mp.State='MP' AND cg.State='CG' AND mh.State='MH';
```

which returned `13`

Comment: Working fine in SQL but in code level i have to do some changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a relational division problem. A generic approach is to aggregate and filter with a `having` clause that counts how many distinct `state`s can be found in the table:

```
select docid
from mytable
group by docid
having count(*) = (select count(distinct state) from mytable)
```

This assumes no duplicate `(docid, state)`. Otherwise, you need:

```
having count(distinct state) = (select count(distinct state) from mytable)
```

Comment: I want to get for Specific state. LIke MP, CG or MP, MH or CG, MH depending on user.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, not an elegant but right solution should be:

```
select distinct
    t1.docid
from
    table as t1
join table as t2 on t1.docid=t2.docid
join table as t3 on t3.docid=t2.docid
where
    t1.state <> t2.state
    and t2.state<>t3.state
    and t1.state<>t3.state
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase 1 if you want to see the N most common values of the docid with what ever state you want

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT  [docid],
         COUNT([docid]) AS value_occurrence 
FROM    [SQLtable]
WHERE   [state] = "what ever state you want"
GROUP BY [docid]
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support that syntax. Many support `LIMIT`

```
SELECT  [docid],
         COUNT([docid]) AS value_occurrence 
FROM    [SQLtable]
WHERE   [state] = "what ever state you want"
GROUP BY [docid]
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: User tagged SQL Server - not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**I think that may solve your problem:**

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT YT.docid
FROM <YOUR_TABLE> AS YT
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND YT.user_id = <ID_USER>
  AND YT.State IN ('MP', 'CG', 'MH')
GROUP BY
  YT.docid, YT.State
```

Comment: Thanks for little help, Dale K.